# Unable to install Ubuntu on Lenovo Legion y530

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, 18.04, live-usb

When I insert bootable disk , starts showing lot of ACPI errors. I hold down shift and run boot options setting acpi = off and ultimately manage to install.

At the end of the installation from the bootable disk, it gets stuck at the final loading screen which is shown after "You need to reboot your system to start using Ubuntu"

I will have to force restart the laptop, once I login system hangs within a few seconds.
Ubuntu 16.04 has problems with wifi drivers where as Ubuntu 18.04 hangs within a few moments of installing.

I am really surprised that such a new Laptop is having difficulty in running Ubuntu 18 where as an old laptop which I had , had no issues during installation at all....

I use rufus to create bootable disk and bios is running on legacy mode.
I did a fresh installation of win 10 in legacy mode.

TIA,

Please help me install this(** crying in the corner **)

Comment: https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Gaming-Laptops-Knowledge-Base/Installing-Ubuntu-18-04-on-the-Legion-Y530/ta-p/4187251 Please use this Link from the Lenovo Community, worked fine for me. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had searched for this post in the first week of september , and they created the post later on. Found it and now laptop is working well. Did follow the steps y mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on my Lenovo Legion y540. I fixed it with installing the 3rd party graphics software (selected the checkbox during installation and set up secure boot). Then after installation when you restart a blue screen will appear and you choose to select the key option and type your secure boot code. everything was fixed in my case after that. I also had an issue connecting to the second monitor and this fixed that problem as well. Seems some graphical software is required which is not installed during the normal installation.