# Unable to download Ubuntu 18.10 into Lenvo y530

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, mount, 18.10

I'm trying to boot Ubuntu 18.10 into Lenovo y530 which already contains Windows 10.
I found a similar question [Unable to install Ubuntu on Lenovo Legion y530](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1073034/unable-to-install-ubuntu-on-lenovo-legion-y530)
 and I followed this link [Installing Ubuntu 18.xx on the Legion Y530](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Gaming-Laptops-Knowledge-Base/Installing-Ubuntu-18-xx-on-the-Legion-Y530/ta-p/4187251).

I followed Ubuntu steps but when I arrived to installation step and I have to choose partition, the only choice I have is `/dev/sdb` which is mounted by the USB. I think that windows or there is something that block the installation to access to the disk in order to choose a mount point.
[image: mount]
[t[image: ][4]]

I'm used to install Ubuntu in other machines and I have the choice between erasing the existent OS or adding Ubuntu with Windows. But today I don't get these choices. 
In windows I have 3 partitions in my hard disk: C:/, D:/ and E:/
How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a partition in windows disk management, and then chose that partition when installing Ubuntu?

Here is how to install on a custom partition:

[How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)